# Table not looping

Tags: php, html, mysql

please find below my table, `$page['body']` retrieves a column from my database, this column is a text box, the text box has multiple lines with multiple comma's on each line, I've been trying to split each line from the column into it's own row in the HTML table and each word(s) before the comma's into each own column in the html table, I hope that doesn't sound confusing sorry.

This is what the text box column in my database record looks like,

> ```
>   more data, even more data
>   some more data, and even more data
>   this is data, and so is this
> ```

and this is what I'm trying to show in the HTML table

```
  | # | First          | Second             |
  | 1 | more data      | even more data     |
  | 2 | some more data | and even more data |
  | 3 | this is data   | and so is this     |
```

the body column from my database looks like this below

> ```
> more data, even more data
> some more data, and even more data,
> this is data, and so is this
> ```

The number's in the left column should auto echo each line by itself, please find below my code, I'm new to coding since October so I hope I haven't made too many mistakes, thank you very much in advance to anyone who replies, it's most appreciated.

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>#</th>
<th>First</th>
<th>Second</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<?php
$pizza  = escape($page['body']);
$pieces = explode(",", $pizza);

foreach ($pieces as $pizza) {
echo "";
echo "<td>$pieces[1]</td>";
echo "<td>$pieces[2]</td>";
}
?>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What is `$pieces[1]` or `$pieces[2]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explode the lines first to get the text for each row.

Then you can create a loop over all rows and extract the columns there.

It would work like this:

```
<?php
//Text to test the output
$text=<<<TEXT
more data, even more data
some more data, and even more data
this is data, and so is this
TEXT;

//just to be sure, the line ending characters are right for
//Windows ("\r\n"), Linux ("\n") and classic Macintosh ("\r")
$text = str_replace("\r", "\n", str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $text));

//exploding the lines
$lines = explode("\n", $text);

foreach($lines as $key => $line) {
    //exploding the columns separated by comma (,)
    $pieces = explode(',', $line);

    //printing the line, the line endings (PHP_EOL) are optional
    //and only used to get a more beautiful result
    if(count($pieces) > 0) {
        echo '<tr>'.PHP_EOL;

        //printing the count column
        echo '<td>'.($key + 1).'</td>'.PHP_EOL;

        //looping the columns
        foreach($pieces as $piece){
            echo '<td>'.$piece.'</td>'.PHP_EOL;
        }
        echo '</tr>'.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the reply, please can you tell me how best to include a key so line one would start with 1, line two would start with 2

Comment: I just edited the answer. I think it's the easiest way to use the array key, since explode creates an array with numeric keys. This key starts with 0, so a `+ 1` is needed every time.

Comment: Hi akrys, I hope you don't mind me asking, I have one more quick question, is it possible to skip the first column without changing the text in the above "$text=" field, for example instead of line one starting with "more data" it would start with "even more data", same goes for the second line starting with "and even more data" instead of "some more data" and so on for each line thereafter

Comment: The columns can be accessed via `$pieces[0]` and `$pieces[1]`. So it's possible to use `unset($pieces[0])` before you loop through the columns or you could even replace the whole `foreach` loop on `$pieces` with `echo '<td>'.$pieces[1].'</td>';`. (Then if you're getting a php notice, saying that index 1 is not defined, you would have to check the existence first: `if(isset($pieces[1])){/*echo ...*/}`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($pieces as $key => $pizza) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo My key is : $key & My value is : $pizza ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, i'm not sure how to paste code in this box, I've posted my edit at http://pastebin.com/NPrfN5WW the issue i'm having is the data is staying inside one column in the html table instead of going into two columns

Comment: Please remove <tr> </tr> tag under the <tbody> i mean remove <tr> tag outsitde of loop. So it should looks like: 

`<tbody>
        <?php
            $pizza = escape($page['body']);
            $pieces = explode(",", $pizza);
            foreach ($pieces as $key => $pizza) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo "$key"; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo "$pizza"; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php }?>
</tbody>`

Answer (score 0):

Use this.
 print_r($pieces);

It print format of array.then use

```
    foreach ($pieces as $pizza) {
    echo "";
    echo "<td>$pizza</td>";
   }
```

If it's associated array ,use

```
foreach($pieces as $key => $value )
{
echo "";
echo "<td>$key</td>";
echo "<td>$value</td>";
}
```